# Need help in removing the space between the label and input field in lightning-layout-item & lightning-input-field in salesforce lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

How can I remove space between the lightning-layout-item and the lightning-input-field on the record-edit-form in salesforce LWC. I have removed label of the element but the space still existing here, Please find below screenshot in which i need the space in table need to be remove [image]

my code looks like this -

```
`<lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item variant="label-stacked" class="lightninglayout slds-size_1-of-5">
                <div class="titleheadings">March</div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item variant="label-stacked" class="lightninglayout slds-size_1-of-5">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={EstimateMar}> </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item variant="label-stacked" class="lightninglayout slds-size_1-of-5">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={NegotiatedMar}> </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item variant="label-stacked" class="lightninglayout slds-size_1-of-5">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={PlanFieldMar}> </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item variant="label-stacked" class="lightninglayout slds-size_1-of-5">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={ActualFieldMar}> </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>`
```

I really appricate any help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to add variant="label-hidden" in your input field?

Comment: check this answer, I assume this is the same issue https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/395408/lwc-datatable-with-custom-picklist-alignment/395412#395412

Comment: yes I tried this but not sure if its problem with LWC or something, nothing gets hidden if I use the variant="label-hidden" 

so I just loaded custom CSS for this from static resource to hide label

Answer (score 0):

Use `variant="label-hidden"` instead. `label-stacked` places the label above the input, but `label-hidden` instead doesn't render the space for the label at all.